# Highcharts SolidGauge Label Resize Issue

Tags: javascript, extjs, highcharts

Good morning/evening! I've spent most of my day looking at this to no avail, so it's time to appeal to a larger audience...

I'm using a Highcharts "solidgauge" chart wrapped in an ExtJS 4.2.2 container class. When I create the solidgauge, everything looks fine until I try to resize it. When I resize it, the series label moves up and off the gauge.

Good:

[image]

Bad (after resizing):

[image]

The culprit is a "Y" value I need to set initially so the "79%" shows up in the middle of the gauge, instead of way below it. Here's the init code:

```
 me.series = [{
        name: 'Uptime',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:2.5vw;color:black"' +
            '>{y}%</span><br/></div>',
            x: 0,
            y: -65,
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true
        },
        tooltip: false,
        type: 'solidgauge',
        valueField: 'uptime'
    }];
```

The "Y: -65" is causing the "79%" to move up the chart when resized. If I set the X and Y values to 0, the text resizes fine (it's just that the label is too far below the gauge).

I have no idea how to get that label to resize correctly with the chart when it's positioned to anything but [0,0] initially. I've looked at the chart.Render object, various CSS configs, overriding ExtJS event handlers, etc.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to have the label centered inside the gauge AND cause it to position correctly when the chart is resized?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

HTML properties like 2.5vw on label text size can't work in this case, because the chart is a canvas and on render it's like printed on the dom (try to inspect it on browser html dom), doing a dashboard with different charts I solved the problem removing the label, adding the label again, and calling:

```
chart.redraw();
```

next i write my old code to reset font size of labels, maybe something is changet, I were using Ext 4

```
setFieldTitleHeight: function(){
    var view=this.getView(),
        panelHeight=view.height;
    var newFontSize=Math.floor((panelHeight/290)*16);
    view.items.items[0].getAxes()[0].getTitle().setAttributes({fontSize: newFontSize+'px'});
},

setDataLabelSize:function(){
    var view=this.getView(),
        panelHeight=view.height,
        serie=view.items.items[0].getSeries()[0],
        assi=view.items.items[0].getAxes();

    var newFontSize=Math.floor((panelHeight/290)*16);
    var label=serie.config.label;
    serie.config.label.fontSize= newFontSize+'px';
    serie.setLabel(label);
    Ext.iterate(assi,function(item,index,array){
        item.getLabel().setAttributes({fontSize:newFontSize+'px'});
    },this);
},
```